# How get proper warnings using Cygwin C compiler on Eclipse IDE

Tags: c, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I'm learning "C" so I have installed Eclipse IDE and Cygwin compiler.

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");


//  return 0;
}
```

I have configured this options for Cygwin compiler "-O0 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -fmessage-length=0"

What bothers me is that I'm not getting any "warning" and it should say something about that missing "return" in an "int function".

I let here the console output

```
    11:55:37 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.c
Invoking: Cygwin C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.c"
Finished building: ../main.c

Building target: HelloWorld.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C Linker
gcc  -o "HelloWorld.exe"  ./main.o   
Finished building target: HelloWorld.exe


11:55:38 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 602ms)
```

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the standard. You don't have to (explicitly) return value in main function, so you don't get warning.

[ISO/IEC 9899:TC2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), 5.1.2.2.3 says:

> (...)
>
> reaching  the  } that  terminates  the main function  returns  a  value  of  0.
>
> (...)